# Why is my server route being appended to the beginning of all my hyperlinks?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, hyperlink, codeigniter-url

I have recently started messing round with CodeIgniter and ran into problems when doing standard hyperlinks through either HTML or using the anchor function, as all hyperlinks append my server route on the start. So say for example I had written a standard hyperlink in my view such as `<a href="www.testsite.com">Test site</a>` it would return `http://localhost/test/index.php/test/www.testsite.com` when I click the link? 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but guessing it maybe something to do with routing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have not added the protocol in front of the link in your view.  Your browser is assuming that `www.testsite.com` is an internal link and treating it exactly the same as it would treat `test/path/to/resource.php` (as a relative link).

Add an `http://` to the front of your URL (in the view code) and everything should just work.

Comment: @Oly - awesome! Don't forget to hit the green check box next to this answer if that solved your problem.

Comment: @OLY you should hit the check if this helped so that sean gets the credit thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your using the url helper and adding your link ontop of the site_url() url function. Can you post your the code your using in your view?